# Log concavity of repeated convolution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, convolution

Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be a smooth and positive function with support in $[-1,1]$, satisfying $\int f(t)\,dt = 1$.  Define $g_1 = f$ and $g_{k+1} = f\ast g_k$.  That is, $g_k$ is the $k$-fold convolution of $f$ with itself.

Is there necessarily some $N$ large enough (depending on $f$) such that $g_k$ is log-concave for all $k>N$?

By the central limit theorem, $g_k$ will of course eventually be well approximated by a Gaussian distribution, which is log-concave.  But log-concavity is not stable under perturbations, so this alone does not make for an argument.

EDIT:  Some further evidence for this hypothesis is the fact that the heat flow of a compactly supported function is eventually log-concave.  Moreover, I have now tested this numerically and it appears to hold.

Comment: Is it stable under convolution ?

Comment: Just a nitpick: I do not think that you would converge to a Gaussian without re-scaling.

Comment: Regarding your question $h = \hat{f}$ would be a continuous function with $|h| \leq 1$. Using that $\hat{g}_k = h^k$ would give you that the limit exists (pointwise) iff in the region in which $|h| = 1$ you have that $h = 1$. I.e.: just test is the inverse Fourier transforms of characteristic functions are $\log$-convex.

Comment: reuns: the convolution of two log-concave distributions is log-concave, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Adrián: I agree that one must rescale the distributions to get a standard Gaussian.  I do not know of any characterization of log-concave functions in terms of the Fourier transform, and I am not sure I understand your point.  By the way, the fact that $f$ is smooth ought to imply that $|\hat{f}(\xi)|=1$ only at $\xi=0$, where $\hat{f}(0)=1$.